# Spark Structural Streaming Output Mode problem

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, pyspark

I am currently looking for an applicable solution to solve the following problem using Spark Structured Streaming API. I have searched through a lot of blog posts and Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, I still can't find a solution to this. Hence raising this ticket to call for expert help.

**Use Case**

Let said I have a Kafka Topic (user_creation_log) that has all the real-time user_creation_event. For those users who didn't do any transaction within 10 secs, 20 secs, and 30 secs then we will assign them a certain voucher. ( time windows is shortened for testing purpose)

**Flag and sending the timeout row (more than 10 sec, more than 20 sec , more than 30 secs) to Kafka is the most problematic part!!! Too much rules, or perhaps i should break it 10sec,20sec and 30 secs into different script**

**My Tracking Table**

[image]

I am able to track user `no_action_sec` by `no_action_10sec`,`no_action_20sec`,`no_action_30sec` flag(shown in code below). The `no_action_sec` is derived from (current_time - creation_time) which will be calculated in every microbatch.

> **Complete Output Mode**
> `outputMode("complete")`  writes all the rows of a Result Table (and corresponds to a traditional batch structured query).
>
> **Update Output Mode**
> `outputMode("update")`    writes only the rows that were updated (every time there are updates).

In this case **Update Output Mode** seems very suitable because it will write an updated row to output. However, whenever the `flag10, flag20, flag30 columns`  have been updated, the row didn't write to the desired location.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Notification") \
    .getOrCreate()

lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("socket") \
    .option("host", "localhost") \
    .option("port", 9999) \
    .load()
split_col=split(lines.value, ' ')
df = lines.withColumn('user_id', split_col.getItem(0))
df = df.withColumn('create_date_time', split_col.getItem(1)) \
    .groupBy("user_id","create_date_time").count() 
df = df.withColumn("create_date_time",col("create_date_time").cast(LongType())) \
       .withColumn("no_action_sec",  current_timestamp().cast(LongType())  -col("create_date_time").cast(LongType())    ) \
       .withColumn("no_action_10sec", when(col("no_action_sec") >= 10 ,True)) \
       .withColumn("no_action_20sec", when(col("no_action_sec") >= 20 ,True)) \
       .withColumn("no_action_30sec", when(col("no_action_sec") >= 30 ,True)) \


query = df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

**Current Output**

UserId = 0  is disappear in Batch 2. It's supposed to show up because `no_action_30sec` will changes from null to True.

[image]

**Expected output**
User Id should be write to output 3 times once it triggers the flag logic 10 sec, 20 sec and 30 sec

Can anyone shed light on this problem? Like what can i do to let rows write into output when  `no_action_10sec`,`no_action_20sec`,`no_action_30sec` is flag to True?

**Debug**

OutputMode = Complete will output too much redundant data
[image: OutputMode= "Complete"]

**Mock Data Generator**

`for i in {0..10000}; do echo "${i} $(date +%s)";  sleep 1; done | nc -lk 9999`

> Assume that the row has been showing up in console mode (`.format("console")` ) will send to Kafka for chaining action

Comment: Can you give sample input and expected outputs?